# Enable systemd service in Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to enable a systemd service automatically after successful boot of my STM32MP1 based Avnger96 board. I am using Yocto Project as build system with Ubuntu 20.04. My image recipe to enable systemd service is `example-systemd.bb`:

```
.
.
inherit systemd

SRC_URI = "file://example.sh \
           file://example.service \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable"
SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "example.service"

do_install_append() {

    install -d 644 ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/example.sh ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d

    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/example.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
}

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/init.d"
FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_system_unitdir}/example.service"

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= " systemd"
```

And included in my main image in `local.conf` with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " example-systemd"`

After building the image, `bitbake -e (YOUR_IMAGE) | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=` shows `systemd`.

But in my rootfs I can't find `systemd/system` directory with above service file. And also when I run `systemctl status example` I get the error `-sh: systemctl: command not found`.

**Update**

After including `DISTRO_FEATURES_append= " systemd"` in the `example-service.bb`, in the rootfs `etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` is created and it contains example.service file. But doing `cat example.service` results in `cat: example.service: No such file or directory`. Is this expected?

Can anyone please let me know how to run this service with systemd and how to check if service is installed and executed from linux user space?

And also I have one more doubt: Can both Systemd and Sysvinit exist together and some services are run by systemd and others by sysvinit?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here

Comment: Did you `cat` using the correct path? If the files exists within rootfs - it should be successfully installed

Comment: Yes, I tried to cat from rootfs/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ which is present in build/tmp/work/../example-image/1.0-r0/. I did this within my yocto build system.

Answer (score 4):

Your project might still use `systemv` or something else as init manager instead of `systemd`.

You can enable `systemd` by adding these lines to your `local.conf` (for versions Kirkstone and newer):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " systemd usrmerge"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
```

You can enable `systemd` by adding these lines to your `local.conf` (for versions Honister and older):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
```

Comment: Hello @Odysseus, does adding above lines to `local.conf` remove `sysvinit` things completely? Can `systemd` and `sysvinit` exist together? Because I have some other things in `init.d` and I don't want to remove them.

Comment: I think its not possible to have 2 init managers co-exist but I guess it shouldn't be a problem to have configuration files for both on the target

Comment: Hi @Odysseus, adding above lines to local.conf results in error: `ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'sysvinit' (but [...]images/example-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
sysvinit was skipped: missing required distro feature 'sysvinit' (not in DISTRO_FEATURES)`. And doing `bitbake -e example-image | grep ^INIT_MANAGER=` shows `INIT_MANAGER = "none"`. What could be the issue here?

Comment: @Preeti It seems you have a recipe relying on `sysvinit` but the feature is removed with `DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"` so you can omit that one. But again - I think you need to decide if you want to use `systemd` or `systemv`

Comment: Yes, some other bsp specific recipes are inheriting the `update-rc.d` class. So should I remove line `DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"` from `local.conf?` Will this effect any existing imgae recipes and their functionality?

Comment: Then the `sysvinit` features should get built again and you should not run into this dependency issue. But you will still have the problem that you can only run one init manager and if you enable `systemd` your `systemv` services most likely won't get started anymore

Comment: Hello @Odysseus, after including system config in `local.conf` I ran into this error:
`Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /sbin/telinit conflicts between attempted installs of sysvinit-2.96-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4 and systemd-1:244.5-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4`. Any idea how to what this means?

Comment: @Odysseus with recent versions of poky you will also need the DISTRO_FEATURES "usrmerge", otherwise you'll get the error "systemd was skipped: missing required distro feature 'usrmerge' (not in DISTRO_FEATURES)"

Answer (score 0):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
```

Comment: Hello @Oleksandr, I have already included this in my main image and also `bitbake -e <image> | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=` shows `systemd`. Do I need to include DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd" in the example-systemd.bb also?

Comment: Hello @Oleksandr, please find the **Update** section in original post for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yocto Kirkstone or later, be sure to change the line

`SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "example.service"`

To

`SYSTEMD_SERVICE:${PN} = "example.service"`

I ran into this issue when upgrading from Hardknott to Kirkstone.  Yocto built and installed just fine, but none of my custom services were starting on boot.  I was missing that `:` and it didn't throw an error on build.